# React Native: Function crashing app

Tags: javascript, react-native, crash

My [command prompt log](https://i.stack.imgur.com/b1QLg.png) is here as well as the link to [a video of the error happening](https://drive.google.com/file/d/16P-Xg-il970EasxObKP2-_YpY7M6RkYo/view?usp=sharing). I added a `console.log("rendered _____ page")` to each file to see when they were rendered.

Below I have attached my the code from the project I am currently working on.

I have a function that seems to be crashing the app which is the `_renderPin()` function. It attempts to render the *event* page and then stalls out until expo closes.

I am using **react native** and if I comment out the use of this function, everything runs smoothly.

The app has a tab navigator (which was working completely fine before the function was added) but now stalls when I click on the tab that has this code within it.

I am fairly new to **JS** and **JSX** and I am not sure if there is a syntax error or why this function would be crashing my app.

Thanks.

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import {StyleSheet, Text, View, FlatList, ScrollView, 
TouchableWithoutFeedback, TouchableOpacity} from 'react-native';
import {CheckBox} from 'react-native-elements';
import {MaterialCommunityIcons} from '@expo/vector-icons'

//Options for checkboxes
const options = ['Show Family Speakers', 'Show Activity Rooms', 'Show Main Stage Shows'];

//Main Class
export default class event extends Component {
//Add title to page
static navigationOptions = ({ navigation }) => {
    return {
        title: `Big Event`,
    }
};
//State variables for data manipulation
state = {
    checked: ['Show Family Speakers', 'Show Activity Rooms', 'Show Main Stage Shows'],
    pinned: ['Family 1']
};

//Functions for checkboxes and pinning items
checkItem = (item) => {
    const { checked } = this.state;
    console.log(item);
    if (!checked.includes(item)) {
        this.setState({ checked: [...checked, item] });
    } else {
        this.setState({ checked: checked.filter(a => a !== item) });
    }
};
pinItem = (item) => {
    const { pinned } = this.state;
    console.log(item.description);
    if (!pinned.includes(item.description)) {
        this.setState({ pinned: [...pinned, item.description] });
    } else {
        this.setState({ pinned: pinned.filter(a => a !== item.description) });
    }
};


_renderPin = (item) => {
    const{pinned} =this.state;

    console.log("Attempt to render pin");
    console.log(pinned);
    if(pinned && pinned.includes(item.description)){
        console.log(item.description,"is pinned");
        return(
            <TouchableOpacity onPress={this.pinItem(item)}>
                        <MaterialCommunityIcons name={"pin"} color={"green"}/>
            </TouchableOpacity>
        );
    }else{
        console.log(item.description, "is not pinned");

        return(
            <TouchableOpacity onPress={this.pinItem(item)}>
                    <MaterialCommunityIcons name={"pin-off"} color={"white"}/>
            </TouchableOpacity>
        );
    }
};
_renderSchedule = (item) => {
    const{checked, pinned} =this.state;

    console.log("");
    console.log("Pinned", pinned);
    console.log("Checked", checked);
    console.log("");
    console.log("");
    console.log("Attempt to render item");
    if(checked.includes(item.key)){
        console.log(item.key," rendered");
        return(
            <TouchableWithoutFeedback>
                    <View style = {styles.mainContainer}>
                        <Text style ={styles.times}>{item.header}</Text>

                        <View style={styles.roundedRectangle}>
                            <Text adjustFontSizeToFit style={styles.events}>{item.description}</Text>
                            {this._renderPin(item)}
                        </View>
                    </View>
            </TouchableWithoutFeedback>
        );
    }else{
        console.log("Item Does Not Match");

        return(
            null 
        );
    }
};
/*_renderPinnedSchedule = (item) => {
    const{pinned} =this.state;
    console.log("Attempt to render item");
    if(pinned.includes(item.description)){
        console.log(item.description," rendered");
        return(
            <TouchableWithoutFeedback>
                <View style = {styles.mainContainer}>
                    <Text style ={styles.times}>{item.header}</Text>
                    <View style={styles.roundedRectangle}>
                        <Text adjustFontSizeToFit style={styles.events}>{item.description}</Text>
                        <MaterialCommunityIcons name={"pin"} color={"green"} paddingLeft={40}/>

                    </View>
                </View>
            </TouchableWithoutFeedback>
        );
    }else{
        console.log("Item Does Not Match");

        return(
            null // OR WHATEVER YOU WANT HERE
        );
    }
};*/

render() {
    const { state, navigate } = this.props.navigation;
    console.log("render event page");

    const schedule =[
        {key: 'Show Family Speakers', header: '8:50pm', description: 'Family 1'},
        {key: 'Show Main Stage Shows', header: '9:10pm', description: 'Main Event 1'},
        {key: 'Show Family Speakers', header: '9:35pm', description: 'Family 2'},
        {key: 'Show Main Stage Shows', header: '10:00pm', description: 'Main Event 2'},
        {key: 'Show Main Stage Shows', header: '11:00pm', description: 'Main Event 3'},
        {key: 'Show Activity Rooms',header: '12:00am', description: 'Activity 1'},
        {key: 'Show Main Stage Shows', header: '12:30am', description: 'Main Event 4'},
        {key: 'Show Activity Rooms', header: '2:00am', description: 'Activity 2'},
        {key: 'Show Main Stage Shows',header: '2:30am', description: 'Main Event 5'},
        {key: 'Show Activity Rooms', header: '3:30am', description: 'Activity 3'},
        {key: 'Show Family Speakers', header: '4:00am', description: 'Family 3'},

    ];


    return (

        <View style = {{flex: 1, paddingTop:30, backgroundColor:'black'}}>
            <View>
                <FlatList
                    data = {options}
                    extraData = {this.state}
                    keyExtractor ={(item,index)=>index.toString()}
                    renderItem ={({item}) => (
                       <View><CheckBox
                            title={item}
                            onPress={() => this.checkItem(item)}
                            checked={this.state.checked.includes(item)}
                            containerStyle={styles.checkboxes}
                            textStyle = {styles.optionsText}
                       /></View>
                )}
                />

            </View>
            <ScrollView>
            <FlatList
                style={{paddingBottom:50}}
                extraData={this.state}
                data={schedule}
                keyExtractor={(item,index)=>index.toString()}
                renderItem = {({item}) => (
                    <View>
                       {this._renderSchedule(item)}
                    </View>
                )
                }
            />
            </ScrollView>
        </View>



    );
}
};

const styles =StyleSheet.create
({
pin: {
  flex:1
},
checkboxes:{
  backgroundColor: "black",
    borderColor: "black",
    height: 8
},
optionsText:{
  color: "white"
},
mainContainer: {
    flex:3,
    flexDirection: 'column',
    backgroundColor: 'black'
},
optionHeader: {
    height:50,
},
roundedRectangle: {
    flexDirection: "row",
    marginTop: 10,
    paddingTop: 15,
    paddingBottom: 15,
    marginLeft: 30,
    marginRight: 30,
    backgroundColor: '#3a3a3a',
    borderRadius: 10,
    borderWidth: 1,
    borderColor:"#c4c4c4",
},
events: {
    color: "white",
    /*color: "#c4c4c4",*/
    textAlign: "center",
    paddingLeft: 30

},
separator: {
    height: 1,
    backgroundColor: 'white'
},
times:{
    color: "#c4c4c4",
    paddingLeft: 30
},
optionsChecked: {
    width: 200,
    height: 100,
    backgroundColor: "white"
},
optionsUnchecked: {
    width: 200,
    height:100,
    backgroundColor: "green"
}

});
```

`

Comment: Change if(pinned.includes(item.description)) {...} to if(pinned && pinned.includes(item.description)) {...} and log value of pinned above the statements. I suggest adding debug points, try react native debugger.

Comment: what's the error that you are getting? share some logs or error screen?

Comment: @RishabhBhatia I have attempted the to add more console debugging statements but am not able to get to the page to view any. I have attached a video of this.

Comment: @AustinS Code in the comment above doesn't help? Also try debugging with react native debugger, it will help.